# Need Some Help In Controversial Verbal Reasoning Question

Tags: reasoning

This is a question from Manhattan test prep 5lb book, page 142:

> *A Small Place* is Jamaica Kincaid’s memoir of growing up in Antigua as well as an indictment of the Antiguan government and Britain’s colonial legacy in Antigua. Kincaid blames colonial rule for many of Antigua’s current problems, including drug dealing and selling off land for tourist properties. Kincaid’s critics question why, if the British are responsible for the Antiguan government’s corruption, the British government itself isn’t more corrupt. Kincaid has responded that there must have been some good people among the British, but that they stayed home.
>
> Based on the information in the passage, which of the following would Kincaid most likely agree with?
>
> a. A government can bring about a degree of corruption abroad that the government itself does not suffer from at home.
>   b. Britain has caused corruption in governments throughout its former colonial empire.
>   c. Selling off land for tourism-related purposes is a problem for Antigua.

The answer and conclusion given in the book is a and c only.

> Kincaid’s critics point out that Britain’s government is not as corrupt as Antigua’s. Kincaid makes a witty rejoinder, but does not deny that the British government is less corrupt than Antigua’s. This, coupled with her stated belief that Britain is responsible for corruption in Antigua, justifies the first statement. As for the second statement, it would not be surprising if Kincaid did think this, but no governments of the “former colonial empire” are discussed in the passage except Antigua’s. Finally, the third passage refers to “Antigua’s current problems, including drug dealing and selling off land for tourist properties,” so the third statement is true.

However, I do not agree that kincaid believed that Britain's government was "not at all corrupt". She just does not deny the fact that Antigua is more corrupt than Britain.

See option a, which in a way can be interpreted as Britain is not all corrupt.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see the phrase “not at all corrupt” in the questions. Are you taking the phrase “that a government does not suffer from at home” to mean that there is no corruption at home?

If so, I can see the confusion — it’s badly worded.  The author is using “degree of corruption” as the noun that is being experienced. But, of course, corruption is itself a noun.

I would have said “a government can bring about corruption to a degree that is not experienced at home.” Meaning, that degree of corruption is not experienced at home, although a lower degree may be.

Comment: Yes , I was referring to that particular phrase only...thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

There is no evidence in the text to suggest that Kincaid believes the British to be "not at all corrupt" -- in fact, quite the opposite.  The quip:

> there must have been some good people

implies that "goodness" is a relatively uncommon trait among the British.  A similar example

> Our understanding of human nature suggests that there must have been some "decent" Germans who joined the Nazi party -- but certainly not enough to prevent the rest from committing atrocity after atrocity.

In any case, the justification for answer choice A hinges on the phrase "*degree* of corruption", which is not the same thing as "*lack* of corruption".  If I say, for example, that Bill *is not as good a cook as* Jill, it doesn't mean he's a *bad* cook.  We are only comparing *degree* of skill.

It's a confusing answer, and could be better-written, but I suppose the point of advanced English exams is to test your ability to properly unravel convoluted arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know exactly what Kincaid meant about the good Brits staying at home, but in its deliberate over-simplicity it can be read as a rather caustic remark. Clearly the question of corruption in post-colonial governments is more complicated than the moral character of particular colonial governors: the policies of the imperial government and the tacit agreement of the people back at home are implicated. The "good people" back in Britain were complicit in these acts even though they were just going about their daily lives. So I think we can rule out answer A inasmuch as it suggests the British government in England was corrupt to a lesser degree. Nowhere does Kincaid say  that in uncertain terms.

There is nothing *in the passage* about this pattern being replicated in other nations that were former British colonies. So we can rule out answer B.

That leaves us with C.

Answer C is very a very reductive reading of the passage. It's as if the Ministry of Propaganda had been given a chance to edit the test questions beforehand.